I need help with Gimp 2.10.38 and trackpad
I recently updated my Mac to 15.1.1 Sequoia and now when I open .jpeg images in gimp, the track pad will not resize by pinching in/out like it did before the upgrade.  I then updated Gimp to 2.10.38, latest version and still no good.
Any tips on how to get the trackpad / touchpad to be able to resize by pinching?
here is what the layout looks like currently.....

Ii used to be able to put cursor in the image using builtin trackpad and then pinch in/out to resize. Now when I do that, the image does not move.
